# What is the use of health-check-type attribute

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have deployed one app both in bluemix and pivotal. Below is the manifest file

```
---
applications:
- name: test
  memory: 128M
  instances: 1
  no-route: true
  health-check-type: none //Why we have to use this?
```

In bluemix, without the health-check-type attribute my app is getting started. But in pivotal, I get the below message continuously due to which the app is getting crashed.

```
0 of 1 instances starting
0 of 1 instances starting
0 of 1 instances starting
0 of 1 instances starting
0 of 1 instances starting
0 of 1 instances starting
0 of 1 instances starting
FAILED
```

After passing health-check-type: none in manifest.yml (in pivotal), app is getting started without any issues.

So can someone tell me is it mandatory to use health-check-type attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM Bluemix is on the older "DEA" architecture, while Pivotal is on the current "Diego" architecture.  You can see how the two differ when it comes to the `no-route` option [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#no-route).